# To sort the collection of collection array list object in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
    Class ParentClass 
    {
     private List<ChildClass>;
    }

    Class ChildClasss
    {

    private Date date;
    } 

    List<ParentClass> parentClassList;
```

How can I sort the parentClassList objects with Date attribute of the child class ? Can I use comparator for this ?

My Requirements for the sort are :
    I need the parentClassObject element on the top which has the earliset date in child class  objects.

For Example: Json notation of the object

```
{
     'parentElement1':{
        'childElement1':{
           'date' : '2013-04-05'
                        }
                     },
         'childElement2':{
           'date' : '2013-03-01'
                        }
                     }
                  },
'parentElement2':{
        'childElement1':{
           'date' : '2013-04-01'
                        }
                     },
         'childElement2':{
           'date' : '2013-03-04'
                        }
                     }
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't `private Date date` in the ParentClass then ?

Comment: Since each ParentClass has multiple children, would you compare two ParentClass objects based on the earliest date or latest date of the set of children for each ParentClass?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use comparator for this?

Yes you can.

Precisely how you would do this is unclear ... because your requirements are very unclear.  However, for example, it would be simple to sort a list of `ParentClass` instances based on the date of each one's *first* `ChildClass` instance's `date`.

Whether a `Comparator` is the right way to do this depends on the context.  As Rajan notes: it may be better to make `ParentClass` implement `Comparable<ParentClass>`.

pseudocode:

```
int compareTo(other)
    return -1, 0 or 1 depending on whether
         this.earliestChildDate() < other.earliestChild(),
         this.earliestChildDate() == other.earliestChild(), or
         this.earliestChildDate() > other.earliestChild()

Date earliestChildDate() 
    for each childElement in this.children
         date = smaller of date, childElement.date
    return date
```

If you cache the earliest child date then sorting will be faster.

Refer to the javadocs for `Comparable` and `Collections.sort` for the details of the APIs you need to implement and use respectively.  (If you don't know where the javadocs are,  Google "Java Platform Standard Edition 7 Documentation" and bookmark the page.)

Comment: Can you give a pseudo code for this? I doubt if we can achieve this.

Comment: @Lokesh - Not unless you clarify your requirements.

Comment: I have edited my question to give more details, can you please give me more insight into how I can implement the comparator on parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to have ParentClass implement Comparable, and implement compareTo so that it can handle subclasses in the desired way (for instance, if it's a ChildClass, pay attention to the date attribute).

Answer (score 0):

First of all this design is not good for what you want to achieve. Why would a parent class ever need an info from child class? This will lead to very crude implementations of what you want to achieve.

When you say that you want to create a list of parent class and sort it based on child class values, first question is how do you create parent class objects?

If you create it as : ParentClass p = new ParentClass(); then your code will not work as there is no child class instance and hence no date.

So all you Parent class objects will be created as following:
ChildCLass c  = new ChildClass();
ParentClass p = (ParentClass) p;

or

ParentClass p = new ChildClass();

So your solution will always be crude and non extensible.

I would suggest to change the design.

Comment: The child class  objects are oneToMany relation to the parent.